# Byte code difference in #-values after change Ant to Maven

Tags: java, maven, ant, bytecode

I changed the compilation of a project from Ant to Maven. We still use Java 1.7.0_80. The ByteCode of all classes stayed the same except for a Comparator class. I disassembled the class with `javap -c`. The only differences are in #-values, e.g.:

before: `invokevirtual #2`

after: `invokevirtual #29`

What do these #-values mean? Is this a functional difference or just a difference in naming?

EDIT: The first method in Bytecode before and after:

```
  public de.continentale.kvrl.model.comp.KvRLRechBetragEuroComparator();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        


  public de.continentale.kvrl.model.comp.KvRLRechBetragEuroComparator();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #21                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
```

Comment: There is one thing I missed: The very first line in the Maven version is "Compiled from "KvRLRechBetragEuroComparator.java". This line is missing in the Ant version.

Comment: I've updated my answer based in this comment - it's likely that you haven't specified the `debug` parameter to the javac ant task / maven-java-compiler plugin and the default in ant is off while in maven it is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The #29 refers to an index in the constant table that describes the method being invoked. It would have been better if you had pasted the *full* output of `javap -c`, because the comment at the end of the line indicates the actual method descriptor.

Example of `javap -c` on an invocation of an instance method `test` in class `Z`:

```
   7: invokevirtual #19                 // Method snippet/Z.test:()V
```

You can ignore the # number, as long as the method descriptor in the comment is the same.

### Why

As to the "why" question, it is very likely caused by the debug in the ant and maven compiler task/plugin settings.

By default, the maven-compiler-plugin compiles with the `debug` configuration option set to `true`, which will attach among other the name of the source file, and thing like line number tables and local variable names.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

By default, the ant java compiler has this set to `false`.

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

To compare and check, set the `debug` parameter of the Ant Javac task to `true` and see if that makes the generated .class files the same.

Comment: the real question is why would that change, if `javac` version has not changed. I like the question

Comment: The rest of the line is totally identical. Two things are strange: Firstly, Ant uses the number 1,2,3,4,5, but Maven uses 21,29,30,35,48. Secondly, we converted more than 1000 (really) Java projects without a Byte Code difference, but this project has this special difference in just one class.

Answer (score 0):

Changes are because ANT keeps debug mode to false for its javac command while maven keeps it true.

If you want ANT to produce same .class file or same bytecode as javac in cmd or maven, you need to add one more flag into javac of ANT script.

> debug = "true"